# Vue-multiselect: How to convert object to array for use in options prop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-multiselect

I am using [vue-multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/) like so:

```
    <multiselect
      id="customer_last_name_input"
      v-model="value"
      :options="activeUserProfiles"
      label="lastname"
      placeholder="Select or search for an existing customer"
      track-by="uid"
      :close-on-select="true"
      @select="onSelect"
      @remove="onRemove"
      :loading="isLoading"
      :custom-label="customerSelectName"
      aria-describedby="searchHelpBlock"
      selectLabel=""
    >
```

...that grabs the list of active customers from an Array and then makes them available in a nice select menu.

This works good. However, I need to add another option from another resource (called `customerNone`) to the `options` prop and but the data is returned as an Object like so:

{"uid":1,"lastname":"None Given","firstname":"User","email":null,"phone":null...blah}

The vue-multiselect docs state that the `:option` prop **MUST** be an Array.

**Question: What is the best way for me to handle this in the vue-multiselect component? Here's my attempt to help explain what I am trying to do (not sure if this is the best way to handle it).** Unfortunately, my attempt causes a console error (see below):

I am passing a prop down called `noCustomer` which, if is `true`, I need to use `customerNone` profile on `:options`:

```
<multiselect
      :options="noCustomer ? customerNone : getActiveUserProfiles"
>
```

here's the error:

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "options". Expected Array, got Object
```

**Is there a way I can convert the `customerNone` object to an array of object?** Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the `customerNone` object in brackets at the time that you pass it to the `<multiselect>` like `[customerNone]`.

This syntax creates a new array on the fly, having 1 element that is the object variable:

```html
<multiselect
  :options="noCustomer ? [customerNone] : getActiveUserProfiles"
>
```

*Update for comments*

In order to auto-select the generic option when it's available, use a `watch` on the `noCustomer` prop to set `value` whenever `noCustomer === true`:

```js
watch: {
  noCustomer(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue) {        // Checking that `noCustomer === true` 
      this.value = this.customerNone;
    }
  }
}
```